# How add or delete an item from a tab in a hook?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with hooks and I would like to add or delete an item from my tab.
I don't know how to do it because this tab is an attribute of my hook tab.

```
const [questionResponses, setResponses] = useState(null);
```

I tried this fix but the syntax don't work :

```
setResponses( questionResponses[idQuestion].responses => [...questionResponses[idQuestion].responses,{
                response_text: itemValue,
                response_type: type,
            }]);
```

I tried to use concat(), but it's freezing when the tab responses is not empty:

```
setResponses({
                ...questionResponses[idQuestion].responses, [idQuestion]: questionResponses[idQuestion]['responses'].concat([{
                    response_text: itemValue,
                    response_type: type,
                }])
            });
```

My tab have this structure:

```
[
    {
        "question_id": 1,
        "question_text": "Best time of day",
        "responses": [
            {
                "response_id": 33,
                "response_text": "Morning",
                "response_type": "radio"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "question_id": 2,
        "question_text": "I heard about Marie-France Group via",
        "responses": []
    },...]
```

Could you help me please ? I don't know how to do it

Comment: Can you add some code to show what exactly you are trying. For hooks example you can go through https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-started-with-react-hooks-f0b5c1e3e0e7.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did a mistake when I send my question.

Comment: You need to use ``Array.filter``. Let me try creating example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the code I added https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-liskov-quv5m.

Use `spread` operator for adding value in the existing array.

```
function addRespone() {
  setResponses([...responses, { name: response }]);
}
```

For removal filter the exsiting array to remove the intended item.

```
function deleteResponse(itemIndex) {
  const newResponses = responses.filter((item, index) => index !== itemIndex);
  setResponses(newResponses);
}
```

Check codesandbox link for complete code.